# Why won't this could run?

Tags: javascript, html

This code just wont execute when i open it in my browser google-chrome, been looking at it for over an hour and just cant seem to figure out whats going wrong, im currently studying at college and still learning the basics of javascript

```js
var area = 'N';
var base = 105;
var addon = 0;

area = prompt("Enter Area Code A, F, G, B, N, P, R, C, H, W, Z");

switch (area) {
  case 'A':
  case 'F':
  case 'G':
    addon = base + base * 0.05;
    break;
  case 'B':
  case 'N':
  case 'P':
  case 'R':
    addon = base + base * 0.07;
    break;
  case 'C':
  case 'H':
  case 'W':
  case 'Z':
    addon = base + base * 0.09;
    break;
  default
  addon = base + base * 0.01;
}

alert("Premium is: £" + addon);
```

Comment: The error mesage is god's word, well not really, but it is helpful sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing a colon after `default`. Should be like this:

```
default:
  addon = base + base * 0.01;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch for reference.
Also, it's a good idea to check your browser's developer console to catch errors like this one.

Comment: Thank you so much! i was going crazy trying to figure out why it wasn't working lol